# Add space number angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to know how to add spaces to obtain a number =>1545852125458 => x xx xx xxx xxx xx.

Sorry for my English.

My html :
{{ item.numberDir }}

Answer (score 0):

You should create a pipe for your needs.

Here I can share my pipe, which groups given number by 3 digits

Example: 123456789 -> 123 456 789

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatNumber',
})
export class FormatNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number | string, ...args: unknown[]): string {
    let v = String(value);
    v = v.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    v = v.replace(/\./g, ',');
    let parts = v.split(',');
    let result = parts[0].replace(/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, ' ');

    if (parts[1]) {
      const glueSymbol = args[0] ? args[0] : ',';
      result += glueSymbol + parts[1];
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you not just have  `return value.toString().replace( /(.{3})/g, "$1 " ).trim();` as your entire transform function?

Comment: Not exactly, if a number contains, for example 5 digits, it should be output as 12 345, in your case it will be 123 45, but this is not about the implementation. This is about that David needs to use a pipe for transforming / formatting a number

Comment: Ah I see what you're doing there.